# createNewFile java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES

Tags: android

Estou tentando criar um arquivo excel em um diretório público com o meu app, mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
at br.com.fexus.fretecif.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:57)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
... 10 more

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Frete&Cif.xls: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
at br.com.fexus.fretecif.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:109)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission      denied)
at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
... 12 more
```

Não consigo criar ou abrir o arquivo (no caso porque ele não foi criado).
Já adicionei ao manifest.xml o seguinte código:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Para mais informações segue o trecho do código na minha MainActivity:

```
boolean criou = true;
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString());
file = new File(folder, "Frete&Cif.xls");

try {
    if(!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(WorkbookUtil.createSafeSheetName("Frete&Cif"));

FileOutputStream output = null;

try {

    output = new FileOutputStream(file);
    workbook.write(output);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    criou = false;
} finally {
    if (output != null) {
       try {
          output.close();
          workbook.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    System.out.println(criou);
}
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="br.com.fexus.fretecif" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Fernando, poderia postar seu Manifest inteiro ou pelo menos onde está declarando essas permissões?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde a versão do Android KitKat, apps não podem guardar dados no SD Card como era feito antigamente. Você pode ler os dados, mas só pode escrever dados no seu próprio diretório dedicado. 
Ou seja, não tem como você escrever na pasta /extSdCard/Downloads/

Comment: Então como faria para armazenar no próprio diretório nas versões KiKat em diante? E mais importante porque existe os métodos para essas versões de compilação sem aparecer que foi depreciado ou coisa do tipo? Obrigado pela informação.

Comment: Olá, poderia tentar o seguinte código?     File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), nomeDoArquivo);   e remover o & do nome do arquivo?